# How do I run a loop wherein java is paused each time the loop goes around and values are added to the end of a list if there is user input?

Tags: java, sleep

I don't how to title this question more succinctly. Basically, I want to know how to run a for-loop while each loop invokes a `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep` method and add values to the end of a list that that loop is going through if there is user input.

Here is the relevant code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < printQueue.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Printing " + i + " of " + printQueue.size()
                + "\n" + printQueue.get(i).getJobTime()
                + " seconds remaining."
                + "\nPlease press \"Enter\" to submit a new print"
                + " job.");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(printQueue.get(i).getJobTime());
        if (input.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            input.nextLine();
            int printTime = jobGen.nextInt(10);
            PrintJob job = new PrintJob();
            job.setJobNum(i);
            job.setJobTime(printTime);
            printQueue.add(job);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(
            "Printed " + printQueue.size() + " of " + printQueue.size());

}
```

Where `printQueue` is a LinkedList of different `PrintJobs` which each have a `jobNum` and more importantly a `jobTime`. If the user has pressed the enter key during any individual loop, a new `PrintJob` is automatically generated and added to the end of `printQueue`.

What happens now instead, is that the program just runs and never terminates unless I press the enter key. I know that `hasNextLine` and `hasNext` may block to scan the specified item, but I don't know how else to implement something like this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered moving the input check to another thread?

Comment: @Abion47 I should do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scanner.hasNextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) blocks waiting for input until either a line is available or the end of the input is reached. As a result, you can't use it synchronously to check whether input is available. As @Abion47 suggested, you should move this input processing to a separate thread.